# Spring annotation scan optimization

Tags: java, spring, configuration, annotations

I using annotation configuration for spring context like

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="example"/>
```

But project is fairly large and scanning for both components have much time (10 s for one scan).
Can I configure this in only one scan, that is proceeded in ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `base-package` value can actually contain multiple packages. Try specifying something like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="example.package.one,example.package.two"/>
```

Where you are explicitly specifying only the packages you need.

Answer (score 2):

10s is not much time at all, because it is performed only once - on startup. You can limit the scanned packages by specifying more detailed package names (not just `example`).

You mention "both" - if you have only 2 spring beans, just list them with `<bean>` in the XML and drop the component scan.

Comment: 10s it's time of one scaning, it's fairly large and grow up with project evolution

Comment: @user298061 how many spring beans do you have? Are you sure it is only for scanning, or for initialization of all the beans?

Comment: They are several hundred, but 10 s it's scaning only excluding bean registation